# vue router dynamic import (lazy load) cannot close the navbar

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router, router

I have a header that is controled by an checkbox input,

when the it's checked the navbar will show and vice versa.

I found that when I use vue router dynamic import (lazy load),

after I click the link and direct to another page, the navbar remains open.

But when I import the componenet first, after I click the link, the navbar will close and change the page,
what's the difference between these two methods and why it doesn't close the navbar when using dynamic import ?   (I use vue 2)

```
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
  },
```

//////////////////////////////

```
 import About from '../views/About.vue'

 {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: About
  },
```

here's the template of my header:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="../assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="" />
    </router-link>
    <input type="checkbox" class="navbar-toggle d-none" id="navbar-toggle"
    v-model="toggledNav" />
    <label class="navbar-toggle-hamburger" for="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="hamburger">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="navbar-toggle-close" for="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="x">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-x fa-2x"></i>
      </span>
    </label>

    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/products" class="nav-link">PRODUCTS</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/about" class="nav-link">ABOUT</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/news" class="nav-link">NEWS</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/contact" class="nav-link">CONTACT US</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

.navbar-toggle:checked ~ .nav{
    .nav-item {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what you do mean by "close the navbar" here since we don't have any more context/code/[repro]. But the first one is using a **static** (nothing dynamic here) lazy loaded component while the second one is loading it in an eager manner.

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: It's much more better to use the second option, as it's widely recommended

Comment: @AliGuliyev why is it better? Actually lazy-loading your components is better on pretty much every aspect performance-wise. https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-in-vue-js/

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have added some info. I still don't understand why...